# Json to django models. Python data-type error

Tags: python, json, django

I have got when I want convert json data in django models.
How can I solve it.

```
class Persons(models.Model):
rank = models.IntegerField()
employer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
employeesCount = models.IntegerField()
medianSalary = models.IntegerField()
```

object creater:

```
for json in json_string:
Persons.objects.create(id=json['rank'], employer=json['employer'], employeesCount=json['employeesCount'], medianSalary=json['medianSalary'])
```

json reader

```
f = open('data.json')
json_string = f.read()
f.close()
```

json file:
[
{
"rank": 1,
"employer": "Walmart",
"employeesCount": 2300000,
"medianSalary": 19177
},
{
"rank": 2,
"employer": "Amazon",
"employeesCount": 566000,
"medianSalary": 38466
}
]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is expecting a dictionary. Convert the json string using the builtin library

```
import json
your_json = json.loads(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Th `json_strings` is just a *string*, not a list of dictionaries. You can make use of the [**`json`** module [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to JSON deserialize it:

```
from json import load as json_load

with open('data.json') as f:
    json_data = json_load(f)

Persons.objects.bulk_create([
    Person(
        id=record['rank'],
        employer=record['employer'],
        employeesCount=record['employeesCount'],
        medianSalary=record['medianSalary']
    )
    for record in json_data
])
```

By using `bulk_create` you create the objects in bulk in the database, which reduces the number of roundtrips to the database.